# Remove specific string from arraylist elements containing a particular subsrtring

Tags: java, arraylist

Here is my code for arrayList ,

```
 String[] n = new String[]{"google","microsoft","apple"};
      final List<String> list =  new ArrayList<String>();
      Collections.addAll(list, n);
```

how to remove all the elements that contains`le`from the above list.
Is there any default method or by looping we have to remove manually.tell me how to do it.Thanks.

Comment: what is le? theres no le in the list

Comment: goole,apple here i want to remove this 'le' specific string from list elements

Answer (score 3):

From java 8 You can use

```
list.removeIf(s -> s.contains("le"));
```

Answer (score 2):

use the following code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class RemoveElements {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         String[] n = new String[]{"google","microsoft","apple"};
          List<String> list =  new ArrayList<String>();
          Collections.addAll(list, n);
          System.out.println("list"+list);
          Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator();
          while(iter.hasNext()){
              if(iter.next().contains("le"))
                  iter.remove();
          }

          System.out.println("list"+list);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of javadoc for List:

```
/**
 * Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list,
 * if it is present (optional operation).  If this list does not contain
 * the element, it is unchanged...
boolean remove(Object o);
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Why to `add` and then `remove` ?

Check before `adding`.

```
    String[] n = new String[]{"google","microsoft","apple"};
     final List<String> list =  new ArrayList<String>();
     for (String string : n) {
         if(string.indexOf("le") <0){
            list.add(string);
        }
    }
```

That add's only one element `microsoft`  to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to loop from all the values in the list,
This may help you,

```
    String[] array  = new String[]{"google","microsoft","apple"};
    List<String> finallist =  new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = array.length -1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) 
    {
        if(!array[i].contains("le"))
            finallist.add(array[i]);
    }
```